# .htaccess domain-1/directory-x to domain2.directory-y

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How would I, with .htaccess, do the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain-1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /posts/([a-z0-9_]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain-2\.com/articles/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So that "/posts/" does not become part of the forwarded path?

Example, I want

http://www.domain-1.com/posts/2014/06/17/some-post-title

To forward to

https://www.domain-2.com/articles/2014/06/17/some-post-title

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain-1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)$ https://www.domain-2.com/articles/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```